# Collection of type interface C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, polymorphism, subclass

I've just completed a lab for college, the lab asked me to create an interface `IHasVolume` with a `Volume` method and then to create a class, `Sphere`, that implemented the interface and by default it's method.
I then had to create a `Test` and call the method in my class polymorphically via a reference to the interface.

snippet of my code:

```
IHasVolume i = new Sphere { Radius = 2 };
```

I also had to make a collection of Spheres and call the various methods

```
IHasVolume[] collection = { new Sphere(4), new Sphere(6), new Sphere(9), new Sphere(10), };

        foreach(IHasVolume s in collection)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Volume: " + s.Volume());
            Console.WriteLine("Radius: " + s.ToString());
        }
```

Now I'm not sure I was actully been asked to make the array of type `IHasVolume`,
But I did and it worked, I'm confused as to why it worked though, Sphere is not a subclass of `IHasVolume`, or is it?

Could someone explain this to me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relationship between a subclass and a superclass is similar to that of an implementing class and an interface. You can think of an interface as a pure abstract base class that contains no logic, only public method (and property) signatures.

So yes, your `Sphere` has an is-a relationship with `IHasVolume`, and will behave the same as if you had an abstract `HasVolume` class that was inherited.

Comment: a point worth noting is that interfaces have been introduced in the c# language to distinguish between a completely abstract class and an abstract class with some implementation details because c# does not allow multiple inheritance. The reason is that there are some problems where two base classes define logic for the same method signatures. With interfaces, we do not have this problem, and we can therefore implement several interfaces in the same class.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a subclass, but the behavior would be similar if you had a base class called `HasVolume` instead of an interface.  But with **an important difference**.  Your `HasVolume` base class would require its own implementation of the methods it defines.

This is not the case with an interface.  You defer to the implementer to define the operation, in this case `Sphere`.  This makes sense when you don't need a base implementation.

For your example, you can get the volumes from your array and total them without caring what type of container they are - sphere, cylinder, etc.  They can calculate their own volumes accordingly, but your method doesn't need to be concerned with how exactly they do that.  You just want to know how much beer they can all hold :).

Comment: I came across this issue in another lab, and it seems there is no way to cast or access said method/property in C# or more so that you shouldn't design it like that, is that correct?

Comment: Yeah, it's considered bad design because it defeats the purpose of using an interface.  Once you have to cast it to a specific implementation, you lose the power of abstraction.  Interfaces are great because they don't tie you to doing things one specific way.

Answer (score 0):

If you do something like

```
IBlah blah = new BlahImpl();
```

What you can do as you have in this example is to instantiate a concrete class but assign the resulting object to an interface.

the effect is same as if you had instantiated a class without interface.

Answer (score 0):

You created an array of type `IHasVolume` which means that it's items can be not only a `Sphere` but any class that inherits from this interface...

in your loop you also specified it as a type of the interface which means any object that inherits from this interface will be acceptable...

Answer (score -1):

Interfaces are the ways to achieve late-binding polymorphic
 so when ever a class implement the interface it assure all interface member can be used and you can call it. 
a classic example for interfaces are ICar which represents the car then the models of different cars will implement the ICar interface and so each model can have their implementation.

Comment: Interfaces have nothing to do with late binding.